# Nginx - Rewriting url to $url.php, and if doesn't exist, rewrite to $url/

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I run a Wordpress site with some custom php pages as well.

If the url doesn't end in an extension (`http://example.com/test`) for example, I would like Nginx to try to rewrite it to `http://example.com/test.php` first, and if `test.php` doesn't exist, rewrite it to `http://example.com/test/`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using try_files:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files

For example (untested):

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /test.php
```

Comment: Using that method, `http://example.com/test` only rewrites to `http://example.com/test/`. If the file is actually `test.php`, it returns a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it tries the actual uri then with php

```
try_files $uri $uri.php $uri/
```

Comment: Please note this is dangerous! Try_files *literally* means try files on disk. There's no location re-evaluation going on here so what will happen is that nginx will serve the literal .php file as text and not pass it to PHP. Only the last parameter to try_files causes an internal redirect and thus location re-evaluation.